# How to post data with jQuery

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, mysql

I'm using PHP to submit a very simple data to db. On my page.php, I have a link, by clicking it I insert its id and some other data in the database. For example:

```
echo "<a href='".$base_url."?submit=$page_id'> Submit it</a>";
```

It generates the url like page/test-page/?submit=12

On the top of the page I get the page id with $_GET and insert it to the db in the following way:

```
if (isset($_GET["submit"])) {
        $page_id = $_GET['submit'] //yes, its not secure.       
        //insert in db.     
        //get db success/error msg in $db_msg       
    }
```

How can I submit the data and get the database success or fail message without refreshing the page.

Comment: using a form? http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_forms.asp

Answer (score 4, accepted):

check out the JQuery Documentation about Ajax Functions: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/

you'd do something like

```
 $.ajax({
  type: 'POST',
  url: page.php,
  data: submit=$page_id,
  success: function(){print("success");}
});
```

btw: it is better to use post than get, it just looks cleaner. (at least in my opinion)

Answer (score 1):

Youll need to use a ajax method as per CyrillC's answer.
here is the official docs [ajax jquery](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)

(there is a shortcode for using the POST method)

```
$.post.({ etc
```

the post method hides your data from the browser (get puts it in the query string)
so its cleaner but also better for security

Answer (score 0):

```
<a href="#" onclick="$.post(
    '<?php echo $base_url ?>',
    { submit= '<?php echo $page_id ?>'},
    callback_function(data)
)">Submit it</a>
```

Send a post request to php, and deal with the message ( "data" ) with javascript?

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use AJAX with jQuery. For starters, have a look at the functions [load](http://www.jquery-tutorial.net/ajax/the-load-method/) , get and post [here](http://www.jquery-tutorial.net/ajax/the-get-and-post-methods/) . The methods get and post are the ones used to submit the data to server-side scripting , since you are using GET method in PHP , use GET of AJAX